# PHP/MySql Select Comments Grouped with Replies

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a script to handle comments similar to facebook's status/replies.  Basically, an item can have comments and users may reply to that comment (one level deep maximum).

My tables are set up as follows:

```
Comments: [ Comment_ID | User_ID | Content | etc...]
Comments_Reply: [ Comment_ID | Is_Reply_To ]
```

So if a user replies to comment #555 it appears in the comments table like a regular comment, then also gets a row in Comments_Reply with [ 555 | *New Comment ID* ]

How can I select the comments such that they are in the following order:

```
[ 555 | ....
[ New Comment that replies to 555
[556 | ....
[557 | ....
```

Etc... where the replies appear sequentially after the comment the reply to.  I am using PHP & MySql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think I got what you want now. I don't have a way to test the MYSQL version of this function quickly, but the SQLite version works great and, according to the documentation, the MySQL should work just as great. Might be a better way to do it on MySQL though.

**SQLite:**

`SELECT a.*, IFNULL( b.Is_Reply_To, a.Comment_ID ) as Is_Reply_To FROM Comments a LEFT JOIN Comments_Reply b HAVING(Comment_ID) ORDER BY Is_Reply_To ASC, a.Comment_ID ASC`

**MySQL**

`SELECT a.*, IF( IS NULL(b.Is_Reply_To), a.Comment_ID, b.Is_Reply_To ) as Is_Reply_To FROM Comments a LEFT JOIN Comments_Reply b HAVING(Comment_ID) ORDER BY Is_Reply_To ASC, a.Comment_ID ASC`

This produces these results for my on SQLite.

```
Comment_ID Is_Reply_to
1          1
10         1
11         1
2          2
12         2
3          3
13         3
14         3
4          4
5          5
6          6
7          7
8          8
9          9
15         15
```

Comment: how did this worked as the LEFT JOIN does not have "ON" statement

Comment: @kornesh `HAVING` works if the columns to match in both tables have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use following query

```
$q="select * from comments";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs))
{
 while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
  echo($rd->comment_id);
  $q1="select * from comments_reply where comment_id=".$rd->comment_id;
  $rs1=mysql_query($q1);
  if($rs1 && mysql_num_rows($rs1))
   { 
     while($rd1=mysql_fetch_object($rs1))
     {
       echo($rd1->comments_id);
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: With 10,000 comments, your query would cry for help.